# Client / Server Cryptography for passwords

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, client-server, public-key

I am building a client/server application in C++  and need each client to provide a password.  Obviously I want this to be secure during transport so I have been looking into a way of encrypting the password; so that only the server application can decrypt it again.

The problem I am having is not necessarily getting the functions to work, but rather understanding what it is I need to do in order to relate that into code.  I am trying to understand and have read MSDN (feels like it) but still I am only learning so really need some clear and accurate guidance on my implementation.

**Does this sound right?**

1. I aquire a context to the CSP on both server and client.
2. I generate a key on the server, or load one (whatever).

and then I

export a public key from the server and send it to the client, the client imports the key and then encrypts the password and returns it so that only the server can decrypt it again.
(Fails when I try).

OR, do I then

export a session key, or an exchange key pair ( single public) which is encrypted with the exchange key pair?

Oh I am so lost, I cannot even explain clearly.

Please help me to understand this...

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Still a bit confused but extremely determined to get this working. I could use whats already available and its probably simpler, but I dont want to have to keep jumping around when things get tough or confusing. I should have been more specific with my question, because actually my problems are related to this crypto API and its use.  I have now got past the original error which held me up, so I know I am not far from a working protoype.  Please post any good links CryptoAPI, RSA, Cryptography.  I am sure my madness will be rewarded some day!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what sort of authentication solution you want to be based one. The options are varied.

You could, for example, rely on the underlying OS authentication. You wouldn't need to manage passwords at all. But this requires a somewhat tighter integration with the domain in which your application is running.

Another option is to use HTTPS and simple authentication. It basically uses SSL to encrypt communication and then sends a username/password pair. Pretty simple, and supported by all web servers. You could probably find C++ code quite easily that takes care of this for you (search StackOverflow for such a question) if you don't want to rely on an existing web server like IIS being installed.

Comment: Hi gigantt.com, yes HTTPS and SSL is actually quite familiar to me as I have 5years web dev behind me.  but what about when the message gets there isn't it going to be plaintext - and contain both username and password.  That worries me!  What hashing options do I have? and if I hash a message on the client can I then compare that to whats in D/B so that plaintext password is not available anywhere.

Comment: as long as the transport layer is encrypted (https) you don't have to worry about sending the plain text password. of course, you can hash it with md5 and you should *never* store the plain text version in your db, but you're still basically relying on the security of https (even if it's hashed, someone can sniff the hash and use it..) - hashing the password for transfer probably won't add a whole lot of security for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the encrypted Communication for other things like data transfer, you can use [Challenge-Response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRAM-MD5) for password verification. The Password does not need to be transferred over the network and there is no risk of a replay attack in wich a third party just resends some packets. On the downside, a man in the middle (MITM) attack is possible.

If you need protection from MITM or need an encrypted channel for other communication, you should use TLS with certificates or Public-Key-Encryption with two keypairs.

Comment: Hi Stephan and thank you for replying, So in general would I aquire CSP context, create server key and then send public key to client, so that app can encrypt and send back(or is that niave - I am sure thats what I learned)  or is it more involved.  I have most of the code and can encrypt and decrypt on server but unsure which keys to send to client. I have the option of exporting session keys, exchange keys, or just public key?

Comment: My answer focused on the Challenge-Response part, I see now that the second part is somewhat unclear, sorry. The public key of the server should already be stored in the client, you can then use it to transmit a random session key to the server during connect. I know you can use a clientside private key to prevent replay attacks and all the like, but I do not know how and would head over to TLS or something : /

Comment: Thanks Stephan, and sorry to keep pushing on this(I can't help myself because something tells me I am nearly there!)  Can you explain the process as you see it, because I think thats where I might be tripping up.  I can get the contxt to the csp, on both Server -(S) & Client (C) and I can export any key from (S), either public, private, exchange etc.  The problem is when I send it over RPC to the client no matter which key I use (C) throws a NTE_BAD_VER error.  --> next comment too!

Comment: I have check CSP and is identical on both client and server!  Have tested with both machine over network, and both apps on same machine but still exactly the same error?  What would the normal process be, and why would I want to send the (C)'s session key to (S)? thats new to me? when I thought I wanted to send the public key from (S) to (C) for (C) to encrypt message and send back to (S).  (S) has the private key so can unlock anything that (C) has encrypted using its (S) public key. I may be missing something related to the crypto api, but is my whole perception wrong?  Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

## Do not do anything.

This is very important. Do not implement this yourself.
Repeat do not do anything you will get it wrong.

You should use what is already available. Simply open a connection to an SSL socket and the content of the stream will be automatically encrypted and de-crypted at the other end.

Your application should simply take a username/password tupple and validate if they are correct. Do not attempt to implement the cryptographic part.

Comment: Hi Marten, thanks for your reply but I am worried the problem of security still remains in that scenario because the password would be decrypted into plainntext when it hits the server. This would also mean storing the plaintext passwords in the DB???  What would you suggest as some form of end-point encryption or hashing to prevent this.  I have done RSA at University, and understand the algo but its just the ordering of keys in this particular client/server setup that I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: the issue of storing the pwd in the db as plain text has nothing to do with your question about encrypting the transport layer. indeed, store a hashed and salted version of the pwd in the db. don't log or store the plaintext password in any other way. but, again, this has nothing to do with https.

Comment: Client: (Passowrd PlainText) -> SSL -> Server (Plaintext again) -> hash (one way with salt) -> DB. Personally I would not implement the hashing on the client as that locks you into a single technique for hashing (and a very hard time upgrading clients (or developing a scheme that includes hash versioning and be ready to support forever old versions)).